# What is the complexity of the cmp() in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity

What is the general complexity of cmp() in python?

I have two dicts. Both have the same length, both have the same keys. The keys and values are strings.
What is the complexity of comparing this dicts with cmp()? If the dicts are different then the complexity is different than they are equal?

```
dict1 = {
    'a': 'f',
    'b': 'g',
    'c': 'h',
    'd': 'i'
}

dict2 = {
    'a': 'f',
    'b': 'g',
    'c': 'h',
    'd': 'i'
}

cmp(dict1, dict2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the general complexity of cmp() in python?

There isn't one. `cmp()` simply delegates to the `__cmp__` data model method (and the `tp_compare` slot for "native" types implemented in C), whose implementation is completely arbitrary. So what you need to wonder is what the complexity of `__cmp__` is *for a specific type*.

In order to know what the complexity of `cmp` is *for dicts*, [you'll have to dig into Python 2 code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/249706c1fbce04125d81bd9993e6c010ae30f8e4/Objects/dictobject.c#L1875-L1921) (as cmp has been removed from python 3).

And note that'll only be part of the story, because a collection's `cmp` would be recursive (it would `cmp` its contents and thus the complexity of a specific instance of dict would depend on, well, its specifics).